# Cakephp ajax pagination issue

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to implement the cakephp **ajax pagination** and it's working fine expect for one problem.
the layout is repeating again but only once. What i mean is that first time i click on the pagination link(next/prev/no) the layout repeats again but if i click any pagination link the layout doesn't.

I have followed the tutorial given on the [cakephp's website](http://book.cakephp.org/view/169/View-Changes). Please tell me what wrong am i doing. Any answer

Answer (score 0):

Look [this post](http://nik.chankov.net/2009/05/16/cakephp-ajaxed-pagination-and-sort/). It uses jQuery and obviously you don't need livequery anymore. your case should be:

```
<?php
echo $javascript->link('jquery.min');
?>
```

and then the javascript file will be:

```
$('a[href*=/sort:],a[href*=/page:]').live('click', function(){
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Bear in mind that you have to use RequestHandler Component